# Neovim Treesitter plugin causes abnormally slow startup

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, treesitter

I am new to linux and neovim.

When I use the treesitter plugin, it causes neovim to take roughly 1.2 seconds to startup. My config file is very basic, with just 5 plugins in the plugin file and a small options file. By using the --startuptime command I can see that everything is fine until the last few lines, where "opening buffers" takes about 600ms, and then "first screen update" takes another 600 milliseconds. Everything else happens in under 100ms. Also, running :Lazy inside neovim shows me that all the plugins are loaded in about 20ms.

Is this simply a normal side effect of using treesitter, or is this something I can fix? If so, what can I do to reduce this delay?

I have tried reinstalling neovim as well as all my plugins multiple times.

Comment: Are you opening a particular file when starting nvim or just a blank session? When you remove the treesitter plugin, is the delay gone? When you remove the other four plugins, is the delay gone?

Comment: @tim-phillips The delay occurs when opening a file such as a c++ or python file, but not when starting a blank session. The delay only occurs with treesitter. So if I remove other plugins but not treesitter the delay is there, and if I remove treesitter and kepe other plugins there is no delay. To be clear, I am actually using treesitter as well as textobjects, Enabling treesitter without textobjects results in about 600ms startup (screen update is 600ms, almost no buffer), and I can't enable textobjects without treesitter. Enabling textobjects on top of treesitter adds another 600ms to total.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You might get some traction posting to the github repo: https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues. Maybe some others will share their startup times here.